# SQL Profiler shows multiple calls for one TVF

Tags: sql-server, profiler, set-returning-functions

There is one table valued function in SQL Profiler I have noticed which seems to *"call itself multiple times"*.

The definition doesnt do any odd thing either, it is a query with few `JOINs` and `WHERE` clause with hierarchyid method `IsDescendantOf`

What is happening here? Is it just false alarm?

What are your thoughts?

Thanks in advance

**SQL:BatchStarting**

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetPermissionsForUser](@p0)
',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier',@p0='7A2137C1-A7D4-415C-A5B5-F4C2351217C9'
```

**SP:Starting and SP:Completed**

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GetPermissionsForUser](@p0)
```

**Schema**

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[permission_matrix] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TargetId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Permission] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Options] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_permission] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hierarchy](
    [NodeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntityId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EntityType] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ParentEntityId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [NodePath] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_hierarchy] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([NodeId] ASC)

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPermissionsForUser]
(   
    @userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        op.Id,
        op.TargetId,
        op.Permission,
        op.GroupId,
        op.Options
    FROM [dbo].[permission_matrix] op
    WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM [dbo].[hierarchy] gh
    JOIN [dbo].[hierarchy] uh
        ON uh.EntityId = @userId
        AND uh.NodePath.IsDescendantOf(gh.NodePath) = 1 
    WHERE gh.EntityId = op.GroupId)
)
```

**This is what shows in SQL Profiler**

[image: screenshot of SQL Profiler]

-- Edit

Extended event session does not display that

[image: Extended event session]

Comment: Updated question. That thing does not appear in extended events. It looks like false alarm, but still it would be nice to know why it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first response would be: don't use Profiler. It was deprecated more than a decade ago for a long laundry list of reasons; this specific symptom isn't the most important one, but there are several, as I lay out in this post:

- [Deprecated features to take out of your toolbox – Part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/03/sql-performance/deprecated-features-2)

A much better alternative is [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events). I tried to reproduce your scenario, using the basic TSQL session included with [XEvent Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler) and see exactly one call to the function.

##### As for "why":

I suspect that Profiler is reporting an instance of the function call for every row (or every matching row) involving the underlying mechanics of [`IsDescendantOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/isdescendantof-database-engine) - which must be doing something recursive.

My good friend [Andy Mallon](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/52344/amtwo) reminded me that `hierarchyid` was invented long after investment in Profiler had ceased, so it's not all that surprising to me that it doesn't correctly ignore the noise. I would wager that the symptom goes away if you comment out that line in the function, though it's possible it will still happen as a result of other hierarchy traversal.

But even if you confirm, that is still total speculation. If you want an official answer, you could try hitting Microsoft up with a support case, but I don't know if they'll even take the call - they'll likely tell you what I'm telling you: use Extended Events.

Comment: Good answer! My worry was it is similar issue as when you use UDF with query inside it on the where clause. Since its profiler quirk and extended events don't show that. its a relief. You never know whats happening inside these `SQLCLR`. The tool you mentioned works nice, its much easier to filter things with it, thanks.